# Which of the following sets are closed under scalar multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

(i) The set of all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $(a,b)$ where $a+2b=1$.

(ii) The set of all $2\times2$ matrices whose trace is equal to $0$.

(iii) The set of all polynomials in $P_2$ of the form $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2$ where the product $a_0a_1a_2\le0$.

Comment: (1) Do you mean closed under multiplication by scalars? (2) What have you tried already? (3) Hint: take any element that belongs to the given set, multiply it by an arbitrary scalar c, and see if the new element is also in the set, i.e. whether it satisfies the given condition or not.

Comment: Yes and yes I did, what I did for i) was multiplied everything by 2, and I got 2a+2*2b which is 2 and 2 does not belong to the set I guess.

Comment: For ii) I'm not sure how to prove that and for iii) I think that this can not be less than 0, only equal to 0

Comment: Same idea for (ii). Set up a generic $2\times2$ matrix (say, you can call its entries $x$, $y$, $z$, and $w$) and multiply the matrix by any scalar $c$. Assuming that the trace of the original matrix was $0$, what is the trace of the new matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i) Consider $c\cdot{x}$ where $x \in A = \{(a,b) | a+2b = 1, a,b \in \mathbb{R} \}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{ 1 \}$. Now, $c\cdot{x} = (ca, cb)$ but $ca+ 2(cb) = c$. Hence, $c\cdot{x} \notin A$. Hence, its not closed under scalar multiplication.

(ii) Closed under scalar multiplication. Try to justify yourself.

(iii) Not closed. Consider $p(x) = x^2-x+1$ and $c=-1$.

Comment: Technically speaking, for (i) it's a counterexample for any $c\neq1$.